# Regular expression to validate unique word in text

Tags: .net, regex

I need regular expression to validate text for all words in text must be unique.
for example my text will be like

**valid text->** 
"Advance|Paid|Regular|Next"

**Invalid text->** 
"Advance|Paid|Paid|Regular|Next|Advance"

words are not fix it can be any thing.

Please help me how I can achieve it in .net

Comment: Regular expressions are not appropriate for this problem.

Comment: Do it HAVE to be a regex? I'd say it's easier to do it other ways. Split on | for instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, it is possible using backreferences:

```
(?:^|\|)([a-z]+)\|.+\|\1(?:\||$)
```

That will match expressions with repeated words, with the first instance of the word as a group. Either negate it to see if words are repeated, or use a replace to remove the words.

To use spaces instead of `|`:

```
\b([a-z]+)\b.+\b\1\b
```

Answer (score 3):

I do not think you can achieve that with regular expressions, unless the list of words is explicitely known (like in enum).

However, in .Net, you can do it very easily in  multitude of other ways.

For starters, let's try C# and Linq:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

string myText = "aaa|bbb|ccc|aaa";
var parts = myText.Split('|');
var uniques = parts.Distinct();
if(uniques.Count() != parts.Length) throw new ArgumentException("Not unique!");
```

Comment: correction - I forgot about backreferences. Indeed, see PeterNLewis answer and my comment to see how the detection could be achieved with regex. The idea in regex is that ANY duplication is a fault, so if the backreference hits any full token delimited by | - then the text is invalid.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure about .net, but a regular expression that will find a word followed by another matching word would be:

```
\b(\w+)\b.*\b\1\b
```

That is, a word break, a sequence of word characters, a word break, any number of any characters (except line breaks) and then the word repeated, with word breaks around it.

Not all regular expression engines will allow \1 to reference a previous match within the same regular expression.

Comment: hm.. that'd mean that `(^|\|)([^|]+)(\||$).+?\1` would detect exactly what the author wants?

Comment: yep, .Net's regex engine supports backrefs: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/thwdfzxy.aspx

Comment: @quetzalcoatl Not quite, even if you change the backref to the correct `\2`, that would match e.g. `Sub|Submarine`.

Comment: @veredesmarald: very true! I've mistaken backref-matching with regex-matching and had the idea that the middle group would not match when the last didn't - which of course is not true. The correct expresison would rather look like `((?<=^|\|)[^|]+(?=\||$)).+?\1` so the group is defined along with delimiters, but without capturing them. Thanks for the note!

Comment: FYI: on the .Net's lookahead/lookbehind: http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/46/CSharp-Regular-Expressions-Cheat-Sheet

Answer (score 1):

This is simple with LinQ

```
string curText = "Advance|Paid|Paid|Regular|Next|Advance";
string valid = string.Join("|", curText.Split('|').Distinct());
if(valid.Length != curText.Length)  
    // error.....
```

Answer (score 0):

Why using RegEx for this at all? Simply check the number of occurences of string X in the input and check if it is at most 1. In your example splitting at "|" should be easy (could be done via RegEx, but simply tokenizing the string should be easier).